# How did the author get the $4 \times 4$ metric tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor

The author takes this metric:

[image]

...and converts it to the form highlighted in yellow below. How did he do this? Note - I'm new to GR and upper level physics in general.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation:

$$ ds^2 = g_{\alpha\beta}dx^\alpha dx^\beta $$

is [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation). When an index is repeated as an upper and lower index it is summed over. So the notation is a concise form of:

$$ ds^2 = \sum_{\alpha=0}^3 \sum_{\beta=0}^3 g_{\alpha\beta}dx^\alpha dx^\beta $$

$g$ is the metric tensor written as a matrix:

$$g = \left(\begin{matrix}
-e^{2\Phi}c^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{1-\frac{b}{r}} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & r^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & r^2\sin^2\theta
\end{matrix}\right)$$

Note that $x^\alpha$ means the $\alpha$th component of the four-vector $\mathbf x$, not $x$ raised to the power $\alpha$.

Comment: Good catch on that last edit, I'm new to GR (as you may have suspected) so I was going to ask that next. Quick note though - did you mean $ds^2 = g_{\alpha \beta} dx^{\alpha}dx^{\beta}$?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat: oops, yes :-)

Comment: Is the four-vector **x** is defined as **x** $=(dt,dr,d\theta,d\phi)$ ?

Comment: d$\mathbf x = (dt, dr, d\theta, d\phi)$

Comment: @whatwhatwhat you really need to spend some time reading up on the Einstein notation and tensors. There's a lot more here that you need to understand e.g. the difference between upper and lower indices. I can't really cover all this in an answer.

Comment: Understood. I plan on taking a few classes on relativity. But for now, I have a presentation due in 8 hours so I will be asking a lot of rookie questions. Please forgive me :)

Comment: The superscripts on $x^0=ct$, $x^1=r$, $x^2=\theta$, $x^3=\phi$ just tell us that $x=(ct,r,\theta,\phi)$ right? Why did this need to be explicitly stated?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat in GR we commonly switch between different coordinate systems so $\mathbf x$ isn't necessarily in polar coordinates. We tend to use the notation $x^\alpha$ to make it clear the equation isn't specific to any particular choice of coordinates.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat if you have more related questions it might be better to ask them [in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) rather than as more questions on the main site. The chat room is more suitable for discussing things.